# Deconstruct Values from Array/Object And Convert At Same Time

Tags: typescript

Is there a clean(er) way to convert/alter the values while deconstructing them from an array/object at the same time? For example, I could do the following, but it seems so messy.

```
const test = {
  a: 123,
  b: 321
};

const { a, b } = (({a, b}) => ({a: a.toString(), b}))(test);
```

I could also do the following but I try to avoid `let` over `const`.

```
const test = {
  a: 123,
  b: 321
};

let { a, b } = test;
a = a.toString();
```

Comment: What you've done first of all looks good to me, just don't do it as a one liner, instead define the mapTestToWhatever function and do like const { a, b } = mapTestToWhatever (test);

Answer (score 1):

Just use the good old fashioned property access:

```
const a = test.a.toString(), {b} = test;
```

Destructuring does not modify or convert any values.